# display Mysql query results on onClick() using Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm beginner with Ajax scripts and I'm trying to build a script that displays Mysql queries results when the user clicks on a link.
I've thought about using the onClick() function calling an Ajax script.
Here is my code :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/course/format/topics/ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="stitre">
    <a href="#" onclick="display()" id="link1" class="link"> Link 1</a>
</div>
<div id="one"> </div>
<div id="stitre">
    <a href="#" onclick="display()" id="link2" class="link"> Link 2</a>
</div>
<div id="one"> </div>
```

My ajax.js code :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
for (var i=1; i<3; i++) {
    var id = document.getElementById("#link" + i);
    function display() {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "myphp.php",
            data: "id=" + id,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                if(msg.success) {
            $("#one").html(msg);
                } else {
                    alert("error");
                }
            }
        });
    };
}
});
```

and finaly, myphp.php :

```
<?php
    require_once('config.php');
    mysql_connect($CFG->dbhost, $CFG->dbuser, $CFG->dbpass);
    mysql_select_db($CFG->dbname);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    if($return = display($id)) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
    echo json_encode($reply);
?>
```

For now, nothing is displayed when I click on the links.

Comment: if ($return **==** display($id))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues.

1. Inline event handlers (`onclick="display()"`) are bad. jQuery provides an easy mechanism for binding event handlers to elements, you should use it.
2. Your `display()` function isn't globally scoped, it's only visible inside the scope of the anonymous function passed to `.ready()`. What this means in practice is when you click on your `<a>` elements they're trying to execute a function they can't see.
3. Declaring a function inside a `for` loop in the way you have will result in a single function using the values of the last iteration.
4. Your `id` variable is a DOM element, not a string, so passing it as part of the AJAX call data likely won't pass the value you want.
5. The `id` attribute on HTML elements is a unique identifier, so does in fact need to be unique. Having two `<div id="one">` elements (or other elements with the same `id`) isn't valid.

Try the following instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myphp.php",
            data: { id: this.id },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg.success) {
                    $("#one").html(msg);
                } else {
                    alert("error");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The `$(document).ready()` ensures that the code doesn't execute until the elements exist (the DOM is ready). The `$('.link')` selects all elements with the class `link` on them (your `<a>` elements). The `.click()` function adds a `click` event handler to all of those elements. The `e` parameter of the anonymous function is passed the jQuery normalised event object as an argument.

The call to `e.preventDefault()` prevents the default behaviour (following the link), and finally the call to `$.ajax()` submits the AJAX call. I've removed `async: false` because it shouldn't be needed. Note that inside the event handler function `this` refers to the element that triggered the event (so the specific `<a>` element you clicked on).

I haven't addressed the issues with the HTML, but the list of issues above should give you a basis to correct those for yourself.

I'm not a PHP programmer so I can't really speak to the validity of your server-side code. I'd also recommend installing [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) if you're using Firefox, otherwise learning how to use your browser's developer tools (hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to open them) since it will tell you about any JavaScript errors that are being thrown.

Comment: I've tryed your code that I understand.
I still have no results, even if i only write echo "success"; in myphp.php

Comment: @Pierrev.d.Erle The `dataType` property passed to `$.ajax()` sets the expected data type of the server response. If you set that to `json` then your code expects the server to return valid JSON, and jQuery will attempt to parse the response text as JSON. In the case that the response *isn't* valid JSON - and the string `"success"` isn't - that parse will fail, and the `success` callback of the AJAX request won't be executed.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand. Thanks for your explanations !
Actualy, I think that Moodle blocks my Ajax code for some reasons I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your success callback:

```
success: function(msg) {
    $("#one").html(msg);
}
```

`msg.success` doesn't exist. Besides you don't need to check for success, you already know it has been successful because the success callback is being called!

Comment: The `success` callback is executed when the AJAX call receives a response successfully, that doesn't automatically imply any server-side validation passed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change PHP script,

```
//Some thing
$reply['success'] = "Success"; //Create an associative array which is going to be input of json_encode()
if($return = display($id)) {
    $reply['success'] = "Some Success Message";
} else {
    $reply['error'] = " Some Error Message";
}
echo json_encode($reply);
```

In ajax,

```
$.ajax({
            ...
            ...
            success: function(msg) {
                if(msg.success) {
            $("#one").html(msg);
                } else {
                    alert("error" + msg.error);
                }
            }
        });
```

And also check your php version, some lower version will not support json_encode(). 
Note: The above code is not actual. But i hope that will give you some idea to do your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

### Might be this way using with class instead:

```
<div class="stitre">
   <a href="#" onclick="display(this.id)" id="link1" class="link"> Link 1</a>
</div>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="stitre">
  <a href="#" onclick="display(this.id)" id="link2" class="link"> Link 2</a>
</div>
<div class="one"></div>
```

then just use this function this way, no need of `doc ready`:

```
function display($id) {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "myphp.php",
        data: {id:$id},   //<----------send like this
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            if(msg.success) {
                $($id).next(".one").html(msg);
            } else {
                alert("error");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

### Note:

```
<div id="stitre">
   <a href="#" onclick="display()" id="link1" class="link"> Link 1</a>
</div>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="stitre">
  <a href="#" onclick="display()" id="link2" class="link"> Link 2</a>
</div>
<div id="one"></div>
```

Other issue is that `you are using same id for multiple dom elements`, which is not valid at all. Either you can `change id to class instead.`

Comment: That *is* an issue, but it's only one of several. A correct jQuery approach to solving this problem wouldn't require that line anyway.